# Material Design CSS specifications

Tags: css, material-design, style-guide

**Are there Google- or other reference CSS3 style sheets available for Material Design?**

Google's [Material Design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) guidelines are written using Android layout units. The only Google-sanctioned CSS-based framework I can find is the [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/material.html) polyfills, but they're too heavy for pure styling.

As a result I've ended up modeling my own CSS3, which is pretty imprecise.

I've done the requisite Googling for Material Design css, styletsheets etc but haven't been able to find any decent references.

Because Material Design is more of an interaction than a style specification, ideally it'd be something that polyfills the interactive/UX parts of Material Design such as easings, transitions, etc in CSS

---

Btw I find the Material Design documentation very well written but it's weird to me that Google went through the trouble of designing a responsive UX framework and didn't bother to specify it in basic CSS.

Comment: Not sure that this is on-topic for UX StackExchange, but I happen to know the answer so I'll give it below...

Comment: This is definitely off topic, but I'm not sure what site to migrate it to.  I'm putting it on hold for now, but I'll try find out where to migrate it to in the mean time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a couple of CSS frameworks for Material Design, not including Polymer:

Materialize: http://materializecss.com/

Material Design for Bootstrap: http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/

There's also https://material.angularjs.org/#/ if you *happen* to be using AngularJS, but that might be a little bit heavy for your liking too.

Comment: Thanks! Materialize looks like a well-crowdsourced effort (53 contributors), and the interactions look quite authentic.